# Show that 2 is not primitive modulo $p=2^{2^n}+1$ for $n\ge 2$, p prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that 2 is not primitive modulo $p=2^{2^n}+1$ for $n\ge 2$, p prime. My problem is that I can't prove by contradiction, because logically I can't say "suppose there isn't $m<\phi(p)$ such that m is the order of 2." One way or another I would have to actually find this m, won't I? I could really use your help here.

Comment: Hint: $2$ has a really small order mod that prime (which is easy to find), compared to $p$.

Comment: Do you mean that if $2^{2^n=m}\equiv -1 \mod p$ then I should raise it all by 2?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $2^{2^{n}} \equiv -1 \pmod p$ we have $2^{2^{n+1}} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, so for $m=2^{n+1}$ we have $2^m \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Since $m < p - 1$ it means that $2$ is not primitive root modulo $p$.